# how to handle span class drowpdown in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

[image]

I am not able to click and select the value from dropdown by using XPath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ProcessTypeIGCombo']/span")).click();
```

MY HTML code is as below:

```
<input class="ui-igcombo-field ui-corner-all" readonly="" style="float: left; display: block; position: absolute; height: 20px; width: 99.7921%;">
```

for more details please use the screenshots

Comment: <input class="ui-igcombo-field ui-corner-all" readonly="" style="float: left; display: block; position: absolute; height: 20px; width: 99.7921%;">

Comment: can you also share the code which you have written to click it?

Comment: @kamal post your HTML code. and error stack trace not able to read out complete HTML from your images.